# play-json on AST with type parameters

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, shapeless, play-json

I am trying to create play-json reads and writes for an AST that basically looks like this

```
abstract sealed trait Rule[A] {
    def roomId: Option[Long] = None
    def valid(in: A): Boolean
}

abstract sealed trait ValueRule[A, B] extends Rule[A] {
    def value: B
}

abstract sealed trait NoValueRule[A] extends Rule[A]
case class OnlyDuringWorkHours(override val roomId: Option[Long] = None) extends NoValueRule[((ResStart, ResEnd), Center)] {
    override def valid(in: ((ResStart, ResEnd), Center)): Boolean = true
}

case class MaxLeadTime(override val roomId: Option[Long] = None, override val value: Int) extends ValueRule[ResStart, Int] {
    override def valid(in: ResStart): Boolean = true
}

case class MaxDuration(override val roomId: Option[Long] = None, override val value: String) extends ValueRule[(ResStart, ResEnd), String] {
    override def valid(in: (ResStart, ResEnd)): Boolean = true
}

case class Rules(centerId: Long, ruleList: Seq[Rule[_]])
```

my attempt at doing this looks like this

```
object Rule {
    implicit def ruleReads[R, V](implicit rReads: Reads[R], vReads: Reads[V] = null): Reads[Rule[R]] = {
        val theVRead = Option(vReads)
        val nvr = ???

        if (Option(theVRead).isDefined) {
            val vr = ???
            __.read[ValueRule[R, V]](vr).map(x => x.asInstanceOf[Rule[R]]).orElse(__.read[NoValueRule[R]](nvr).map(x => x.asInstanceOf[Rule[R]]))
        } else {
            __.read[NoValueRule[R]](nvr).map(x => x.asInstanceOf[Rule[R]])
        }
    }
    implicit def ruleWrites[R, V](implicit rWrites: Writes[R], vWrites: Writes[V] = null): Writes[Rule[R]] = Writes[Rule[R]]{
        case nv: NoValueRule[R] => Json.writes[NoValueRule[R]].writes(nv)
        case v: ValueRule[R, V] => Json.writes[ValueRule[R, V]].writes(v)
    }
}
object ValueRule {
    implicit def valueRuleReads[R, V](implicit rReads: Reads[R], vReads: Reads[V]): Reads[ValueRule[R, V]] = {
        val mlt = Json.reads[MaxLeadTime]
        val md = Json.reads[MaxDuration]
         __.read[MaxDuration](md).map(x => x.asInstanceOf[ValueRule[R, V]])
        .orElse(
            __.read[MaxLeadTime](mlt).map(x => x.asInstanceOf[ValueRule[R, V]])
        )
    }
    implicit def valueRuleWrites[R, V](implicit rWrites: Writes[R], vWrites: Writes[V]): Writes[ValueRule[R, V]] = Writes[ValueRule[R, V]]{
        case mlt: MaxLeadTime => Json.writes[MaxLeadTime].writes(mlt)
        case md: MaxDuration => Json.writes[MaxDuration].writes(md)
    }
}

object NoValueRule {
    implicit def noValueRuleReads[R](implicit rReads: Reads[R]): Reads[NoValueRule[R]] = {
        val odwh = Json.reads[OnlyDuringWorkHours]
        __.read[OnlyDuringWorkHours](odwh).map(x => x.asInstanceOf[NoValueRule[R]])
    }
    implicit def noValueRuleWrites[R](implicit rWrites: Writes[R]): Writes[NoValueRule[R]] = Writes[NoValueRule[R]]{
        case odwh: OnlyDuringWorkHours => Json.writes[OnlyDuringWorkHours].writes(odwh)
    }
}
object OnlyDuringWorkHours {
    implicit val format: Format[OnlyDuringWorkHours] = Json.format[OnlyDuringWorkHours]
}

object MaxLeadTime {
    implicit val format: Format[MaxLeadTime] = Json.format[MaxLeadTime]
}
object MaxDuration {
    implicit val format: Format[MaxDuration] = Json.format[MaxDuration]
}

object Rules {
    import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
    import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

    implicit val rulesReads: Reads[Rules] = (
        (JsPath \ "centerId").read[Long] and
        (JsPath \ "ruleList").read[Seq[Rule]]
    )(Rules.apply _)
    implicit val rulesWrites: Writes[Rules] = (
        (JsPath \ "centerId").write[Long] and
        ???
    )(unlift(Rules.unapply))
    implicit val format: Format[Rules] = Format(rulesReads, rulesWrites)
}
```

This leaves me with two problems.

The first is that if I plug in the expressions I feel are correct in Rule.ruleReads for the two instances of `???`, `Json.reads[NoValueRule[R]]` and `Json.reads[ValueRule[R, V]]` respectively I get the following compile error

```
cmd16.sc:8: type mismatch;
 found   : play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Helper.this.OnlyDuringWorkHours]
 required: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Helper.this.NoValueRule[R]]
        val nvr = Json.reads[NoValueRule[R]]
                            ^cmd16.sc:11: type mismatch;
 found   : play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Helper.this.MaxLeadTime]
 required: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Helper.this.ValueRule[R,V]]
            val vr = Json.reads[ValueRule[R, V]]
                               ^
```

the second is if I leave the `???` so that that portion compiles it then fails to compile the rules object with

```
cmd17.sc:71: No Json deserializer found for type Seq[cmd17Wrapper.this.cmd16.wrapper.Rule]. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.
        (JsPath \ "ruleList").read[Seq[Rule]]
                                  ^
```

I can make the Rules reads / writes a Format instead and get a very similar error

I think the problem with 2 is the difference between Rules containing a `Seq[Rule[_]]` and me defining an implicit read that should cover any *specific* rule but not a rule that could be anything

Any ideas how I can get this working? I feel like this should be possible but maybe it isn't.

Comment: Could you also describe how you expect the result JSON to look like? Do you have a known fixed format? Or whatever that can be encoded and decoded by the Scala code is OK? The problem is that your `Rule` subtypes are quite similar in shape so the obvious solution is to add some explicit type discriminator into the JSON. Is that OK? Or do you really want to discriminate actual types by subtle differences in JSON?

Comment: adding something into the json that does not explicitly appear in the case class is totally fine although not something I have tried yet, I guess in that case I would have to write custom reads and writes for each then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I think you should try some macro-based library that can be found by googling for "play json sealed trait" such as [Play JSON Derived Codecs](https://github.com/julienrf/play-json-derived-codecs) , here is a hand-written solution that might work for you:

```
object PlayJson {

  import play.api.libs.json._

  // fake types instead of your real ones
  type ResStart = Int
  type ResEnd = Int
  type Center = Int

  sealed trait Rule[A] {
    def roomId: Option[Long] = None

    def valid(in: A): Boolean
  }

  sealed trait ValueRule[A, B] extends Rule[A] {
    def value: B
  }

  sealed trait NoValueRule[A] extends Rule[A]

  case class OnlyDuringWorkHours(override val roomId: Option[Long] = None) extends NoValueRule[((ResStart, ResEnd), Center)] {
    override def valid(in: ((ResStart, ResEnd), Center)): Boolean = true
  }

  case class MaxLeadTime(override val roomId: Option[Long] = None, override val value: Int) extends ValueRule[ResStart, Int] {
    override def valid(in: ResStart): Boolean = true
  }

  case class MaxDuration(override val roomId: Option[Long] = None, override val value: String) extends ValueRule[(ResStart, ResEnd), String] {
    override def valid(in: (ResStart, ResEnd)): Boolean = true
  }

  case class Rules(centerId: Long, ruleList: Seq[Rule[_]])


  object CompoundFormat {
    final val discriminatorKey = "$type$"

    private case class UnsafeFormatWrapper[U, R <: U : ClassTag](format: OFormat[R]) extends OFormat[U] {
      def typeName: String = {
        val clazz = implicitly[ClassTag[R]].runtimeClass
        try {
          clazz.getSimpleName
        }
        catch {
          // getSimpleName might fail for inner classes because of the name mangling
          case _: InternalError => clazz.getName
        }
      }

      override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[U] = format.reads(json)

      override def writes(o: U): JsObject = {
        val base = format.writes(o.asInstanceOf[R])
        base + (discriminatorKey, JsString(typeName))
      }
    }

  }

  class CompoundFormat[A]() extends OFormat[A] {

    import CompoundFormat._

    private val innerFormatsByName = mutable.Map.empty[String, UnsafeFormatWrapper[A, _]]
    private val innerFormatsByClass = mutable.Map.empty[Class[_], UnsafeFormatWrapper[A, _]]

    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[A] = {
      val jsObject = json.asInstanceOf[JsObject]
      val name = jsObject(discriminatorKey).asInstanceOf[JsString].value
      val innerFormat = innerFormatsByName.getOrElse(name, throw new RuntimeException(s"Unknown child type $name"))
      innerFormat.reads(jsObject)
    }

    override def writes(o: A): JsObject = {
      val innerFormat = innerFormatsByClass.getOrElse(o.getClass, throw new RuntimeException(s"Unknown child type ${o.getClass}"))
      innerFormat.writes(o)
    }

    def addSubType[R <: A : ClassTag](format: OFormat[R]): Unit = {
      val wrapper = new UnsafeFormatWrapper[A, R](format)
      innerFormatsByName.put(wrapper.typeName, wrapper)
      innerFormatsByClass.put(implicitly[ClassTag[R]].runtimeClass, wrapper)
    }
  }

  def buildRuleFormat: OFormat[Rule[_]] = {
    val compoundFormat = new CompoundFormat[Rule[_]]
    compoundFormat.addSubType(Json.format[OnlyDuringWorkHours])
    compoundFormat.addSubType(Json.format[MaxLeadTime])
    compoundFormat.addSubType(Json.format[MaxDuration])
    compoundFormat
  }

  def test(): Unit = {
    implicit val ruleFormat = buildRuleFormat
    implicit val rulesFormat = Json.format[Rules]

    val rules0 = Rules(1, List(
      OnlyDuringWorkHours(Some(1)),
      MaxLeadTime(Some(2), 2),
      MaxDuration(Some(3), "Abc")
    ))

    val json = Json.toJsObject(rules0)
    println(s"encoded: '$json'")
    val rulesDecoded = Json.fromJson[Rules](json)
    println(s"decoded: $rulesDecoded")
  }
}
```

calling `PlayJson.test` prints

> encoded: '{"centerId":1,"ruleList":[{"roomId":1,"$type$":"OnlyDuringWorkHours"},{"roomId":2,"value":2,"$type$":"MaxLeadTime"},{"roomId":3,"value":"Abc","$type$":"MaxDuration"}]}'
>
> decoded: JsSuccess(Rules(1,List(OnlyDuringWorkHours(Some(1)), MaxLeadTime(Some(2),2), MaxDuration(Some(3),Abc))),)

The main idea is to have `CompoundFormat` for the sealed trait that stores mapping between the class name and the corresponding `OFormat` for each child.

---

**Update** (about reflection concerns)

Here is a non-generic version of `CompoundFormat` that I expect to be similar to what a macro-based library can generate (actually I expect good macro-based library also handle a case when some of the children of the sealed trait are singleton `object` rather than `class` which this code does not handle):

```
object ExplicitRuleFormat {
  implicit val format: OFormat[Rule[_]] = new ExplicitRuleFormat()

  private object InnerFormats {

    final val discriminatorKey = "$type$"
    implicit val onlyDuringWorkHoursFormat = Json.format[OnlyDuringWorkHours]
    final val onlyDuringWorkHoursTypeName = "OnlyDuringWorkHours"
    implicit val maxLeadTimeFormat = Json.format[MaxLeadTime]
    final val maxLeadTimeTypeName = "MaxLeadTime"
    implicit val maxDurationFormat = Json.format[MaxDuration]
    final val maxDurationTypeName = "MaxDuration"
  }

}

class ExplicitRuleFormat extends OFormat[Rule[_]] {

  import ExplicitRuleFormat.InnerFormats._

  override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Rule[_]] = {
    val jsObject = json.asInstanceOf[JsObject]
    val name = jsObject(discriminatorKey).asInstanceOf[JsString].value
    name match {
      case s if onlyDuringWorkHoursTypeName.equals(s) => Json.fromJson[OnlyDuringWorkHours](jsObject)
      case s if maxLeadTimeTypeName.equals(s) => Json.fromJson[MaxLeadTime](jsObject)
      case s if maxDurationTypeName.equals(s) => Json.fromJson[MaxDuration](jsObject)
    }
  }

  override def writes(r: Rule[_]): JsObject = r match {
    case rr: OnlyDuringWorkHours => writeImpl(rr, onlyDuringWorkHoursTypeName)
    case rr: MaxLeadTime => writeImpl(rr, maxLeadTimeTypeName)
    case rr: MaxDuration => writeImpl(rr, maxDurationTypeName)
  }

  def writeImpl[R <: Rule[_]](r: R, typeName: String)(implicit w: OWrites[R]): JsObject = {
    Json.toJsObject(r) + (discriminatorKey, JsString(typeName))
  }
}
```

and with that `test` becomes:

```
def test(): Unit = {
  import ExplicitRuleFormat.format
  implicit val rulesFormat = Json.format[Rules]

  val rules0 = Rules(1, List(
    OnlyDuringWorkHours(Some(1)),
    MaxLeadTime(Some(2), 2),
    MaxDuration(Some(3), "Abc")
  ))

  val json = Json.toJsObject(rules0)
  println(s"encoded: '$json'")
  val rulesDecoded = Json.fromJson[Rules](json)
  println(s"decoded: $rulesDecoded")
}
```

Effectively you just replace `implicit val ruleFormat = buildRuleFormat` with `import ExplicitRuleFormat.format`.

Comment: this seems to work great, thank-you.  wish it wasn't so much code to grok but it definitely does what I want it to do, thank-you.

Comment: do you think you could get around the reflection by defining enums for each rule and pattern matching?

Comment: @Ir1sh, I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to avoid here that you call "reflection". If you mean could you explicitly provide some other names than `Class.getSimpleName`/`Class.getName` - yes, you obviously can. If this is something else - you should state it more explicitly.

Comment: why is the unsafe format wrapper unsafe? is it not because it uses reflection? Does ClassTag use reflection?

Comment: @Ir1sh, no, it is "unsafe" because `OFormat`, which is a combination of `Reads`+`OWrites`, is invariant so I have to use an explicit cast in `format.writes(o.asInstanceOf[R])` that relies on the fact that what I put there will actually be of the proper sub-type. If you make `CompoundFormat` non-generic and use explicit pattern-matching instead of `innerFormatsByClass`, I think you can avoid that cast. P.S. `ClassTag` is resolved by the compiler at compile time. All I need is a `runtimeClass` that in Java I would have to pass explicitly to `addSubType`   instead. In Scala I can use this trick.

Comment: @Ir1sh, to clarify my point I added non-generic `ExplicitRuleFormat` code to my answer. I believe it to be effectively the same as my original implementation but with the difference of being tailored specifically to the `Rule[_]` trait.